# How to find out encryption and hashing algorithm info in IIS?

Tags: iis, ssl, encryption, hash

For certification purposes, I need to report what encryption and hashing algorithm is being used in the server/website. It's an IIS site on Server 2008. It is set to require 128-bit SSL.

Where can I see encryption and hashing algorithm info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A co-worker found a place where you can see SSL configuration settings. It still doesn't tell you explicitly what is your encryption and hashing algorithm but you do get some idea:

- Go to Start, click on run and type “gpedit.msc”.
- Go to Local Computer Policy --> Administrative Templates --> Network
  --> SSL Configuration Settings